# Automorphism of a nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group.

Suppose that $f\colon G\to G$ is an endomorphism which induces an identity on abelianization of $G$.

Because of lots of down-votes, I modify my question and give what I have thought.

**Question:** Why $f$ is an automorphism?

I saw a paper which claims that $f$ is an automorphism without giving any clue.

I thought that this is well-known result in group theory.

I found [a webpage](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/IA-automorphism_group_of_nilpotent_group_equals_stability_group_of_lower_central_series) which contains related arguments but it already assumes an automorphism of a nilpotent group is given!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: As an extension to the comment above. Adding your thoughts and motivations for the question has a positive impact on you aswell, people won't downvote it and are more likely to upvote it :). Thanks

Comment: While I don't disagree with the above comments, I find the downvotes and votes to close rather extreme! It is a perfectly good and nontrivial question. There are many other questions around equally lacking in context that just get answered. The answer is yes, but the proof is nontrivial.

Comment: You have edited the question, but you have still not expressed any ideas about how to solve the problem. There are two separate problems, proving $f$ is surjective and injective. Have you any ideas on either of them?

Comment: Well. Both directions seem nontrivial. If this is too easy question, then I will think about this question for a few days. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some quick hints.

To show $f$ is surjective, it is enough to show that if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ generate $G$ modulo $[G,G]$, then they generate $G$. Let $\gamma_1(G) > \gamma_2(G)=[G,G] > \cdots$ be the lower central series of $G$. Thjen $\gamma_2(G)$ is generated modulo $\gamma_3(G)$ be the commutators $[x_i,x_j]$ and since $\gamma_{i}(G) = [\gamma_{i-1}(G),G]$ for $i>1$, by induction prove that $\gamma_i$ is generated modulo $\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ by the commutators $[x_i,y_j]$, where $y_j$ generate $\gamma_{i-1}(G)$ modulo $\gamma_i(G)$.

The injectivity of $f$ comes from the property that finitely generated nilpotent groups are Hopfian. See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_nilpotent_implies_Hopfian